# Home page not showing the main content area: Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, template, static-content

I am using Athlete Theme on my website: Site was working fine but today when i have checked it is missing the main page content and footer section.

When I directly put all my contents to 1column.phtml template its start showing all the contents. But if Tempalte use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>` its stop showing anything on page.

I have tried by changing the template from 1column.phtml to 2column and also checked the style display:none but still no luck:

Here is the URL http://159.203.70.155/

Please help me on this issue thanks

Comment: most likely you have a PHP error that breaks all the rendering beyond that. Check your Magento system and exception logs, and of course php error logs as well (apache / nginx / php)

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue actually one of the block generate this issue i have removed the following block so page start working:

```
<div class="fc_container fc_border_box  clearfix">
<div class="fc_grid_6"> 
{{block type="athlete/product_list_featured" category_id="10" products_count="6" product_columns="3" block_title="Sale" template="catalog/product/products_slider.phtml"}}
</div>
<div class="fc_grid_6"> 
{{block type="athlete/product_list_featured" category_id="9"   products_count="6" product_columns="3" block_title="What's New" template="catalog/product/products_slider.phtml"}}
```